# Отследить переходы по страницам в SPA (Страница одна, контент заменяется)

Tags: javascript, spa

Делаю расширение хром (jquery, js).

Есть сайт, реализован как SPA. То есть, страница сайта всегда одна, а при "переходах" на другие страницы, контент текущей страницы просто заменяется, при этом, изменяется URL.

Как мне отслеживать такие "фейковые" переходы по страницам?
Нужно при смене страницы, получать новый URL.
Пример SPA сайта: https://gmail.com/

Comment: Думаю, вам поможет [MutationObserver](https://learn.javascript.ru/mutation-observer)

Comment: `let obs = new MutationObserver(() => { console.log(location.href) }); obs.observe(document.body, {subtree: true, childList: true})`